# Can't resurrect dead and/or disabled NPC using console commands

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim-vr

In *Skyrim VR*, I had made Ondolemar a follower at some point and put him in Castle Volkihar to live. Something went wrong and he started fighting with everyone as though he was an enemy. So I took him outside and killed him.

As he lay dead, I don't remember if I disabled him to keep my yard clean but recently I wanted to see if I could rehabilitate him.
So when I tried to use a console command on him, you would see him flash in and appear for like a millisecond but would not remain. What is going on? If he can't be console commanded because I disabled him, how can I restore him?

Comment: Is this question about Skyrim VR or about the regular non-VR version? (Asking to make sure that your question has the correct information and tag) Also, what edition are you playing?

Answer (score -3):

You broke your game, dont use console commands until you really have to, Dont kill essential NPCs. NEVER!!
You wont appreciate that solution, but just start a new game without using the console.

Thats all i have to say.

Comment: What do you mean "I broke my game?"
Everything else in my game works fine!
I don't have to start a new game.
I just can't console command him.

Comment: Just learned that Ondolemar is not an essential and can be killed. The problem lies in something else